# Login with different roles in Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, thymeleaf

I am designing a login page (Thymeleaf and Spring security) and want to provide user option to chose his role during login . A user can have admin and/or user role . I am using spring security for authentication purpose. I am stuck at this and could not find a way out.

Comment: Please  share your code if any.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is :--

1.) Choose/Save a number or some identical word to figure out your User & Admin.

For Example - 1 is for Admin & 2 is for User.

2.) Put your admin/user role in Session so that you could identify the user role throughout your web application.

PS - i know its a old school method but still very effective.